# Execution failed for task ':advertising_id:compileDebugKotlin' #Flutter #VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I ran a code one of my client gave me, but this error is comming when i debug or do flutter.
I did flutter clean , flutter pub get but still the same. Help Plz

My flutter version
Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 135454af32 (12 days ago) • 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
Engine • revision 3316dd8728
Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\advertising_id-2.2.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\os\operando\advertisingid\AdvertisingIdPlugin.kt: (24, 31): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':advertising_id:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 22s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

### I ran the code with --stacktrace

```
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
[        ]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
[        ]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
[        ]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[        ]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 19s
[   +1 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[        ] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own     
scripts or plugins.
[   +1 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
[        ] Watched directory hierarchies: []
[ +574 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 23.1s)
[   +8 ms] "flutter apk" took 27,388ms.
[  +14 ms] Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[  +11 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:408:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:184:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:109:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1209:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
d_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +263 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 254ms
[  +44 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[ +142 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +4 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: Could you please provide a clean formatted error log and build log? Did you try the suggested run with `--stacktrace`? Did you verify everything is up to date to try to avoid the type mismatch `Activity` != `Activity?` ?

Comment: i ran with --stacktrace this is not the full log but where the error came